# tns not on PATH after installing NativeScript

Tags: nativescript

I ran through the NativeScript install guide to completion: http://docs.nativescript.org/angular/start/ns-setup-win

After completion I ran the tns doctor command only to find that tns was not installed on my PATH.

Both the JAVA_HOME and ANDROID_HOME PATH variables were created.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: its should in directory like this one `C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Roaming\npm` if you installed as global and npm should be in path so it should be recognized by default

Comment: Thanks @MarekMaszay.  I checked and roaming\npm wasn't in my path.

There must have also been an issue with my initial npm install because I cleaned out the files that were there and reinstalled and it appears to be OK now

Comment: Does it works now ?

Comment: Yes, tns all configured and working fine.  doctor is complaining about missing/misconfigured Android SDK's, but I can deal with that.  Thanks!